Evening Too is a Time to Perform Mitzvot; How, Without Tzizit, do we Effectively Remember/Trigger Their Performance?
Premise #1: Mitzvot are performed by day and night. This idea really needs no proof, but I cite a Kesef Mishna (Laws of Shema 1:2) nonetheless:
"לפי שמעשה המצות שנזכר בוהיה אם שמוע נוהג בין ביום בין בלילה" - "the performance of Mitzvot that is mentioned in the second paragraph of Shema occurs by day and night..."
Premise #2: Tzizit's purpose is to remind us to perform the mitzvot; the Tzizit-reminder only occurs by day. The same Kesef Mishna:   וזכירת המצות שעל ידי ציצית שנזכר בויאמר אינו נוהג אלא ביום" - the Mitzvot reminder via Tzizit that is mentioned in the third paragraph of Shema only operates during the day"
Premise #3: the reason that the reminder mechanism of Tzizit can only be utilized by day is because one can only see Tzizit via daylight (and not in the dark). Duh!
Premise #4: ONLY the seeing of Tzizit (wearing a rubber band on your wrist or uttering verses of the Torah or utilizing sticky notes are NOT fully effective Mitzvot reminders) triggers an effective Mitzvot-reminder that, in turn, leads to the performance of Mitzvot: (Menachot 43b and Lechem Mishna cited below).

ותניא אידך וראיתם אותו וזכרתם ועשיתם ראיה מביאה לידי זכירה זכירה מביאה לידי עשיה And it is taught in another baraita: The verse states: “That you may look upon IT and remember all the commandments of the Lord and do them.” This teaches that looking at the ritual fringes leads to remembering the mitzvot, and remembering them leads to doing them.

The Lechem Mishna sums up this Premise #4 well: כיון שאין הזכירה באה אלא ע״י ציצית כמש״ה וראיתם אותו וזכרתם “Since the remembering ONLY comes via tzizit as it states ‘you shall see them and remember …’”
Question - evening too is a time to perform Mitzvot; how, without Tzizit, do we remember and thus trigger an evening performance? Put it another way - why did God create a daytime-only reminder for Mitzvot that occur day and night?
A possible answer - a dose of a daytime, visual Tzizit Mitzvot-reminder is sufficient to last through the evening too.
Thoughts?
Unfortunately, several of the comments below fail to account for the Gemarra and Lechem Mishna cited here which support Premise #4 - Lechem Mishna (Gimmel):


Which mitzvos are you refferring too? Most mitzvos that are bein adam lichaveiro are mostly active suring the day, when you're with people.

Remember that most people would sleep most of the night - there's not much to do when it's dark enough that you can't even see your own tzitzis!

"Premise #2: Mitzvot need a performance reminder ... Premise #4: only the seeing of Tzizit triggers a Mitzvot-reminder ..." By that logic, women wouldn't be able to keep any Mitzvot, even during daylight hours.

For premise #2, I don't see how the Kesef Mishna that you quote shows that Mitzvot need a performance reminder. All that quote shows is that Tzizit are a Mitzvot reminder. It could be just an added bonus, so to speak.

@Tamir Evan. Thank you for your comments. I disagree. My sense of the Gemara is that that THE way to remember Mitzvot is through Tzizit; nothing else will do. I believe ALL the commentators agree with this understanding. Let’s, for example, examine a quote of the Lechem Mishna:        כיון שאין הזכירה באה אלא ע״י ציצית כמש״ה וראיתם אותו וזכרתם
“Since the remembering only comes via tzizit as it states ‘you shall see them and remember …’”

Premise 4 is wrong. Tzitzis remind us to do mitzvos but it's not true that one can only do mitzvos after seeing his tzitzis. Furthermore, if one is reminded during the day then you will continue to remember into the night having seen them during the day. It's illogical that one would suddenly forget to do mitzvos after shkia

@Dude - I disagree. You misread the premise. Tzitzit is the only way to have an effective remembrance.

@GratefulD Where is the Lechem Mishna?

@GratefulD and then you suddenly forget as soon as it's nighttime? No.

Premise 4 is wrong. Who told you that?

@Qwetrl - Premise 4 is correct - the cited Lechem Mishna echoes what all the meforshim agree to (based on the Gemarra cited) - only the seeing of Tzizit triggers an effective Mitzvot-reminder that, in turn, leads to the performance of Mitzvot.

@GratefulD You keep saying “only the seeing of Tzitzit”. You keep using that word. But so far, literally not a single one of the Mepharshim you attribute that statement to have used such a language. Stop misquoting them.

I hired a Jew to live in China and wear tzitzit. When it is night for me he looks at his tzitzit, is reminded to do mitzvot, and he sends me a text to tell me to do mitzvot.

@ClintEastwood Lol.

Since you're asking for thoughts and not sources:
During the day you can see your Tzizit, but you also see everything else, hence you are constantly being distracted. Tzizit are there to help you refocus.
During the night you cannot see anything, and thus can concentrate on the task at hand. No need for Tzizit to refocus. Keeping in mind that when you can't see anything, you can't do much; you either sleep or use candlelight for specific tasks.
A final thought: Chazal teach us (Eruvin 65a) that the night was created for learning Torah, and while learning there is no need for constant reminders to do Mitzvot.

One can use the same idea as expressed in Gemara Menachos 43b in a slightly different context.

The Sages taught in a baraita: The Jewish people are beloved, as the Holy One, Blessed be He, surrounded them with mitzvot: They have tefilin on their heads, and tefilin on their arms, and tzitzis on their garments, and a mezuza for their doorways. Concerning them David said: “Seven times a day I praise You, because of Your righteous ordinances” (Psalms 119:164). This alludes to the two tefilin, the four tzitziot, and the mezuza, which total seven.
And when David entered the bathhouse and saw himself standing naked, he said: Woe to me that that I stand naked without any mitzva. But once he remembered the mitzva of circumcision that was in his flesh his mind was put at ease, as he realized he was still accompanied by this mitzva. After he left the bathhouse, he recited a song about the mitzva of circumcision, as it is stated in the verse: “For the leader, on the Sheminith: A Psalm of David” (Psalms 12:1). This is interpreted as a psalm about circumcision, which was given to be performed on the eighth [bashemini] day of the baby’s life.

The point here that we actually have 8 markers to remind us about all the mitzvos. Tefilin and mezuzah contain parshios, such as 2 paragraphs of Shema', that have requirement of performance of mitzvos by day and by night just like the tzitzis by day. We still have mezuzos on doorposts of our houses at night. Also bris-millah is a reminder by virtue of gematria ברי"ת = 612, i.e. it is itself a mitzvah and reminds us about other 612.
